# Can every real number be written as an infinite series of rational numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

That is,  $$   \forall r \in \mathbb{R},\exists \left \{ q_{n} \right \}_{n\in \omega_{0} }\subset \mathbb{Q}   \ such \ that \ r = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } q_{n}
$$

So essentially the reals can be constructed from the rationals by countable summation. Has this statement been proven or disproven? If it has I'd like to see the proof either way.

Comment: $\left \{ q_{n} \right \}_{n\in \omega_{0} }\subset \mathbb{Q}$ means an enumeration of the rationals ? If so, the answer is yes

Comment: If $r_n \to x$ then $x=(r_1)+(r_2-r_1)+(r_3-r_2)+....$.

Answer (score 5):

For every $r \in \mathbb{R}$, just define $(q_n)$ by induction, by :
$$q_0 = \lfloor r \rfloor, \quad \text{and} \quad \forall n\geq 1,\ q_n=\dfrac{\lfloor 10^n r \rfloor}{10^n}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} q_{k}$$

Comment: I think it should be said that this is simply the decimal expansion.

Comment: @tomasz At least for the fractional part of non-negative numbers $r$.